# How to Swap First and Last Characters from Input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to programming, learning Python3 from an online course. This exercise asks me to write a program which reads a string using `input()`, and outputs the same string but with the first and last character exchanged (example: Fairy becomes yairF). There is likely a simpler way to do this with more advanced functions, however, for the purposes of this exercise, I am supposed to write the program using only classes, substrings and indices. Here is what I have now:

```
myString = input()
newString = (myString[1:len(myString)-1])
print(myString[len(myString)-1],newString,myString[0])
```

Using the example of input 'Fairy', this outputs 'y air F', which is not what I'm looking for. I also tried

```
myString = input()
newString = (myString[1:len(myString)-1])
newString[0] = myString[len(myString)-1]
newString[len(newString)-1] = myString[0]
print(newString)
```

However, line three gave me: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. So I'm guessing I can't assign new values to places in an index. My other approach, below, also gave me an error:

```
myString = input()
newString = (myString[1:len(myString)-1])
lastString = str(myString[len(myString)-1],newString,myString[0])
print(lastString)
```

Line three gave me: `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`, so it seems that I can't combine them that way. Any tips on handling this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> temp = "abcde"
>>> temp[1:-1]
'bcd'
>>> temp[-1:] + temp[1:-1] + temp[:1]
'ebcda'
>>>
```

In short, python has magnificent string slicing syntax. You can do magic with it.

Comment: Please don't name a variable `str`, it's the name of the type. And a test if `len(s) < 2` would be useful.

Comment: @Kay: a test if len(s)<2: I'm not writing a complete function, but giving a hint that is - I hope - sufficient for the asker to handle the problem on his own.

Comment: @Kay: Works for strings of any length as written.

Comment: @martineau, no. `temp = 'X'; temp[-1:] + temp[1:-1] + temp[:1] == 'XX'`

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
>>> temp = "abcde"
>>> temp2 = list(temp)
>>> temp2[0],temp2[-1]=temp2[-1],temp2[0]
>>> temp = ''.join(temp2)
>>> temp
'ebcda'
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in python are immutable, so you can't simply do this:

```
mystr[0] = mystr[-1]
```

To swap letters in a string, you can make it into a `list` then simply change the order of the list:

```
mystr = "abcde"
mylist = list(mystr)
store = mylist[0], mylist[-1]
mylist[0] = store[1]
mylist[-1] = store[0]
print ''.join(mylist)
```

Prints:

```
ebcda
```

Comment: Could written more succinctly as: `store[0], store[-1] = store[-1], store[0]`. However doesn't handle empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for `temp = 'x'` as well.

```
temp[-1] + temp[1:-1] + temp[0] if temp[1:-1] else temp[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input()
wordLength = len(word)
print(word[wordLength-1]+word[1:wordLength-1]+word[wordLength-wordLength])
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon to this question too, and after reading the answers I found probably the easiest way to do it:

```
mystring= input(cantastif) 

print(mystring[-1]+mystring[1:8]+mystring[0])
```

I deliberately used an example as I think it is easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input()

slice_mid = string[1:-1]
slice_end = string[-1:]
slice_beg = string[0]

print (slice_end + slice_mid + slice_beg)
```

This is what my noob brain came up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
def front_back(word):
    word_list = list(word)
    keep_in_mind = word_list[0], word_list[-1]
    word_list[0] = keep_in_mind[1]
    word_list[-1] = keep_in_mind[0]
    return (''.join(word_list))

print(front_back('a'))
```

Comment: The best solution for one-letter-words.

Comment: The others fail when a one-letter-word given.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input()
print(word[-1]+word[1:-1]+word[0])
```

I had trouble with this one - found this explanation online which helped

1. We initialize a variable start, which stores the first character of the string (`string[0]`)
2. We initialize another variable end that stores the last character (`string[-1]`)
3. Then we will use string slicing, `string[1:-1]`, this will access all the characters from the 2nd position excluding the last character.
4. Then we add these three as required forming a new string that has the first and last characters of the original string swapped. And then we will print it.

I had originally added additional variables as placeholders for the first and last character of the string but you can do it only by calling the indexes, slicing, and concatenating the strings.

Answer (score 0):

the below solution can work too as I have tested it.

word = input()

x = list(word)

y = x[0]

x[0] = x[-1]

x[-1] = y

print("".join(x))

thank you.

Comment: How does it work? Why does it help? How is it usefully different from existing answers?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do the following:

```
myString = input()
newString = (myString[1:len(myString)-1])
print(myString[len(myString)-1]+newString+myString[0])
```

Done!

Comment: oh my God... This is not very pythonic either.